# Phaser text event not recognizing listener function

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

I've been pulling my hair out trying to make this work... anyone know what's wrong with it?

I'm trying to use a text object as a button, but the game launches to a black screen and an error.

This is the entirety of the typescript minus the `window.onload` handler that creates the MyGame instance.

```
class MyGame {

game: Phaser.Game;
textStyle: object = { font: "Ubuntu", fill: "black", align: "center" };

constructor() {
    this.game = new Phaser.Game(800, 640, Phaser.AUTO, 'content', { preload: this.preload, create: this.create, update: this.update });
}

preload() { }

create() {

    this.game.stage.backgroundColor = "#eee";

    let buttonPlay = this.game.add.text(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY, "play", this.textStyle);
    buttonPlay.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    buttonPlay.inputEnabled = true;
    buttonPlay.events.onInputUp.add(this.onPlay, this); //line 19

}

update() { }

onPlay() {
    console.log("pressed play");
}
}
```

This is the error that I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Phaser.Signal: listener is a required param of add() and should be a Function.
at i.Signal.validateListener (phaser.min.js:3)
at i.Signal.add (phaser.min.js:3)
at Object.MyGame.create (app.ts:19)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create the game instance in the constructor, instead do it in the onload handler like this:

```
new Phaser.Game(800, 640, Phaser.AUTO, 'content', new MyGame());
```

What happens is that Phaser will call the `create` method on the object you provided:

```
{ preload: this.preload, create: this.create, update: this.update }
```

Inside the method, `this` will then be the object you provided and not the class instance. (Look up how `this` works if you want to know why.)

`onPlay` does not exist on that object so `this.onPlay` will be `undefined` hence Phaser will think you didn't give it a listener param.